# What is Shandilya Mimansa?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, shandilya

I have recently saw a telecast of "Shandilya Mimansa" Katha By Kirit Bhai on [Sanskar TV Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskar_TV). I am bit surprised because I never heard name of any scripture called Shandilya Mimansa. I know about Rishi Shandilya and have read one work Shandilya Bhakti Sutra but I never heard about a Mimansa work by Shandilya. I have tried searching that scripture on internet but didn't find it.

I am curious to know what is Shandilya Mimansa? Is it a work like Mimansa works done by Jaimini and Badarayana or what is it about? & Where can I find original text of Shandilya Mimansa?

You may refer the mentioned telecast on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/z5J3rguFyS4?t=1045).

Comment: Can you update the link with specific timestamp at which he is saying about "Shandilya Mimansa"?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Listen from updated link.

Comment: The Shandilya Mimansa discourse by P.P.Kiriti Bhai in the video is actually of shandilya Bhakti sutra itself.He has just changed the name of shandilya Bhakri sutra to  Mimansa. See the sutra he is saying in the video (2.1.27) is present in shandilya Bhakti sutra text.So both are same.

https://archive.org/details/ShandilyaBhaktiSutra/page/n65/mode/2up

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I have just found one text called Shandilya Mimansa on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ShandilyaShatadutriyaBhashyamShandilyaAndSvapneshwaracharya4323Alm20Shlf2DevanagariMimansa/) Is it same?

Comment: @Pandya - I think that's the work of someone Svapneshwaracharya's Devanagari Mimansa and not Shandilya Mimansa as we can see from the title.Also the word mimansa is often used in many texts as to denote the nature of work i.e. thorough analysis etc.

Comment: @Pandya - We can also call any text which does through  analysis of subject  as XYZ Mimansa text so we can also call Sutras as mimansa in limited form. But not everytime i think.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, you can write an answer :)

Comment: @Pandya - Yes , I will write it stating that both texts are same , only the difference of naming is there in the video.